# What is the first doctor you can reasonably access in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

What's the easiest to access or first doctor you can access in Fallout 4?  Of course more than one is welcome.  This should be the doctor that is easiest to access by a low level character (assume the lowest level character that can reach any doctor), ideally close to Vault 111/Sanctuary.

If a more specific area is needed, you can reference [this map](http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Fallout-4-Map.png) on how dangerous areas are:

[image: Danger vs 'Safe' area Map of Fallout 4]

I'd suggest sticking to doctors that are in the areas of the map which are blue (accessible by most characters below level 16).  If the map isn't available for some reason, this is roughly a 45 degree wedge from Cambridge up into the northwestern corner of the map.

This question originally was: Is there a doctor consistently available before Diamond city?  Given that people interested in this may well search google for terms like doctor, Lexington, Cambridge and Diamond city I am going to leave that in the text as well.

I know there is a traveling doctor in the area (having run into her), but I'm looking for one that is in a fixed location (or very predictable) that players can locate with constancy if they need medical care early in the game.

Comment: I thought she was near the billboard, 3 mattresses and old cars on the west side of the road just north of starlight drive-in, but checking there did not yield a location.

Comment: Build a doctor shop in sanctuary? :D

Comment: There's a roaming doctor/trader in the NE portion of the map, but you'll probably get to Diamond City before you get there

Comment: Vault 81 count? You have to bring them 3 fusion cores to get in.

Comment: This is a vague question, because of the nature of the game.  You may want to narrow down to specific area/s to keep from getting the question marked as being too vague.  With an open world game like Fallout 4, you can literally go to every other location "before" Diamond City.  And just an FYI you probably ran into a travelling doctor, which is like the travelling merchants that you will find randomly at settlements and on the road.

Comment: @dakre18 I would consider anything closer to Vault 111 than Diamond City is to be "before" Diamond City, but you make a good point. It could be made more explicit.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah, it's mostly to avoid it getting tagged as being too broad.  In an open world, saying before a specific area is the same as saying anywhere but the 1 area.  Many good questions easily get put on hold because of wording like that.

Comment: related forum discussion: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164594-fallout-4/72795975

Comment: Considering that Vault 111 is practically at the upper-left corner of the map, and Diamond City is over half-way "down" and about a third "right" on the map, that still leaves a massive amount of territory that could be considered "before Diamond City". Especially when you consider the surface area outside of that region that's covered in water, I'm still pretty sure the list of doctors *beyond* your scope of interest would be smaller.

Comment: How can I make it more specific as to help new players in the first part of the game before they can possibly make it to Diamond city which is typically cited as the first doctor?  My natural assumption based on the question (or what I'm trying to ask) is assuming you're following the main quest path as directly as is reasonable/possible.  I understand it's impossibly broad if you consider that you can put off Diamond city forever by never following the main plot line, but I don't see how that's either the first or most common reading of my question.

Comment: I would hope you could just list a few waypoints and ask if there are any doctors along or near that path: Vault 111, Sanctuary, Concord, Cambridge, Diamond City. Some people are picky though. To make it completely objective, you could probably look at a map and pick some boundaries, and just ask if there are any doctors in that area.

Comment: With your edit, I feel that there are two questions: (1) What doctors, if any, can I consistently access before reaching Diamond City? (This one might refer to location-based or travelling doctors.) and (2) Where are the non-travelling doctors located?

Comment: I re-edited to make it specific to doctors that are easiest to access early in the game.  Hopefully that will do it.  If I can get this one right I'll try add another question for a list of all doctors as I think that is likely also useful, but I think it is a different topic deserving it's own space.

Comment: I'd vote to reopen if I could, but I haven't accumulated enough rep on this SE yet. That map is good.

Answer (score 8):

The doctor in Diamond City was the first one I ran into in my first couple playthroughs. There are a few doctors you could reasonably get to beforehand without going way out of your way, but they're neither a lot sooner nor much easier to get to, so you aren't missing out by just going ahead and continuing to Diamond City instead.

[**Bethany**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bethany)

There's **a doctor in a shack surrounded by radiation west of ArcJet Systems**. The doctor is a ghoul, so the radiation doesn't bother her. If you already have enough radiation resistance, perhaps from the power armor in Concord, then this doctor might be worth visiting. Unfortunately, there's no fast travel waypoint.

[**Patricia Montgomery**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Patricia_Montgomery)

There's **a doctor in Covenant**. Covenant is pretty easy to reach if you go east a bit. You'll have to go through the SAFE test at the door, and she may turn hostile depending on your choices in [Human Error](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Error).

[**Rachel**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rachel)

**There's a doctor you can see in Vault 81**. I often go by Vault 81 on my way to Diamond City, but it's not very far away and you may not even need to fight anything between the two locations, so you're not really gaining much by going here first.

Furthermore, you have to either pass a charisma check or donate three fusion cores to gain entrance. The check isn't too hard, especially if you don't mind loading a few times. You should be able to get past it with some Charisma gear and/or some temporary buffs.

[**Doc Weathers**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Weathers_%28Fallout_4%29)

**There is a traveling doctor.** I usually run into Weathers at Bunker Hill, in the stall next to Deb. This stall rotates between the various traveling merchants. Sometimes Trashcan Carla is there. Weathers can also be found traveling around the northern part of the map. The wiki article says he starts at County Crossing, near the National Guard Training Yard.

If you spread east before going down to Diamond City, you'll probably run into Weathers at some point. Bunker Hill is a fairly easy to reach early hub. You could just as easily get to Diamond City though, if you decided to go that direction instead.

**Make Your Own**

You'll probably get to Diamond City before Level 14, but maybe not, depending on play style. At level 14, you can get Local Leader 2. This, combined with Medic 1, **allows you to build a pharmacy in your settlement**. You can assign a settler here, and get all the services provided by a normal doctor.

Comment: The doctor near ArcJet is [Bethany](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bethany)

Comment: @boomstick Thanks, added that link and Doc Weathers, and the doctor in Covenant.

Answer (score 4):

Covenant has a doctor early game.

Comment: Diamond City can be hard to get to and I personally avoided Vault 81 altogether; another vault with people and their problems... *yay*. Covenant  has a fast travel mat 20 feet from a doctor (that damn door, though).

Comment: Forgot about that one. Added it to my answer. Anybody who comes later: this was not already in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you play, you could encounter Vault 81 before you get to Diamond City. There's a doctor there.

I tend to highly prioritize side-questing and off-the-rails exploration, so that was the first doctor I'd encountered in my first attempt at playing the game.

Aside from that personal experience, I'd pretty much echo what others are saying in comments: It's probably shorter to list the doctors who *aren't* available "before Diamond City" than those who are.